# How to Fix django migrate issue?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I am try to run my django project before run I did makemigrations all my apps and then I run command migrate but I am getting this error I am not able to understand what exactly this error. Please help.[image]

Comment: can you add your models please ?

Comment: sir actually models are many 100 around what you want say  can you brief please

Comment: I think there is an sql syntax error thats why your migrations are not valid.

Comment: When I face issue with migration, I just delete all files under the migrations folders except the files start with __init__. Then do makemigrations and migrate. If the error exist, then the issue is with the code which should be pasted here for people to help.

Comment: SQLite does not support some constraint. so check your fields otherwise you have  to show your model

Comment: If you don’t provide your models is impossible to find the error, probably you have make a syntax error (check your models).

Comment: sir actually project running properly on linux os but i am try on mac os there error is getting. otherwise i could check fields but on ubuntu its migratiing and working fine but when clone and migrate on mac system there this migrate issue getting.